# Using context without any static reference

Tags: android, design-patterns, memory-leaks, singleton

I am trying to access application resources, (string resources to be specific) from a Singleton class. Being Singleton, this class cannot hold any reference to Context objects (to prevent memory leak). While I was looking for other implementations on the net, I came across this two implementation:

1. Create a static context in Application class and use it across the app.
2. Pass context as a parameter to the method that requires it.

I don't want to use the fist one as it also uses a static reference to Context object. I understand that it's ok to have it statically in the Application class of android, but still it looks like a hack.

The second implementation is useless since i don't have any instance of context which I can pass to the someOtherMethod of the singleton.

So I came up with following implementation where I make my Singleton abstract to override its context requiring methods (for ex.  `getString(int resId)` in the code below) when I initialize the singleton instance.

I am curious to know if this can lead to any memory leaks now?

Where am I confused with this approach:

--> The reference to context in the Overridden `getString` is final. I am not sure if that can cause a memory leak or not.

```
    public abstract class SingletonClass{

    .
    .
    .

    private static SingletonClass sInstance;

    private SingletonClass(Context paramContext) {
        // constructor code
    }

    public static SingletonClass getInstance(final Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new SingletonClass(context){
                @Override
                public String getString(int resId) {
                    return context.getString(resId);
                }
            };
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public abstract String getString(int resId);

    .
    .
    .

    private void someOtherMethod(){
        //uses above getString()
    }

    }
```

Comment: Could you share how you are using these strings, and more specifically, why you won't have a `Context` when you are using them?  In most cases, the Activity / Service / BroadcastReceiver / SQLiteOpenHelper / etc. would provide the context, making your singleton somewhat unnecessary.

Comment: I am working on an android game and using Google Play Game Services in it. I thought of singleton as I need to keep a single GoogleApiClient across the app.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does have a memory leak.  The first context passed into `getInstance` will never be garbage collected, since your anonymous class holds a reference to it.  (and there is a static reference to the anonymous class).  e.g., if you call `getInstance(Activity)`, that activity will remain in memory until the process is killed!

Fortunately there is a pretty easy fix to get rid of the memory leak.  You can safely hold onto the application context (`context.getApplicationContext`), which is basically a singleton context for lifetime of the app.

```
public static SingletonClass getInstance(Context c) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new SingletonClass(c.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can depend on activity lifecycle, and require activities to pass reference to your singleton object in onResume method, and clean it in onPause.

```
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  Singleton.getInstance().onResume(this);
}

protected void onPause() {
  super.onResume();
  Singleton.getInstance().onPause();
}
```

Also, you can refresh the instance of `Context` and hold it in `WeakReference`:

```
class Singleton {
  private WeakReference<Context> mContext;

  private boolean hasContext() {
    return mContext != null && mContext.get() != null;
  }

  public static Singleton getInstance(Context c) {
     //do your singleton lazy
     if (!sInstance.hasInstance()) {
       sInstance.mContext = new WeakReference<>(c);
     }
     return sInstance;
  }
}
```

Second case could hold a reference to finishing activity, so i don't suggest it.

Comment: What is the `Singleton` is doing something asynchronous. If the `Context` suddenly get `null`, it would throw an error, won't it?

Comment: @AnkitMundada if your context gets null, than you have nothing to do with context anymore. You can just return null if context is null for resources.

Comment: I meant , in your first method, when i clean context in `onResume()` but if it is still used by an asychronous call of the `Singleton`, won't it throw an exception? Why do you say, 'you have nothing to do with context anymore' if its still being used by the asynch process?

Comment: Use locking then, to avoid exceptions. It is your responsibility - handle asynchronous code, and it is not a common case.